How to Build encodePacked Safe Signatures
Currently attempting to push a deployment of a contract through a Safe. Supposing you have ownership of all private keys, not you should be able to Generate Signatures and safe.execTransaction but current simulation reverts with GS026: Invalid owner provided
private keys are composed of privKeys msg.sender, uint256(1) and uint256(2) and safe uses those same keys as safe owners. Ordering of signatures is ascending according to public address and signatures are aggregated following rsv ordering.
Not sure if there's some logic I'm missing here or if ordering should occur in a different format.
The error seems to arise from the following revert logic:
 if (currentOwner <= lastOwner || owners[currentOwner] == address(0) || currentOwner == SENTINEL_OWNERS)
owners are not address 0, current owner is not a sentinel owner. Error seems to tie to currentOwner <= lastOwner but not sure where the mistake is:
function _generateSignatures(uint256[] memory privKeys, bytes32 digest)
        internal
        returns (bytes memory signatures)
    {
        require(vm.addr(privKeys[0]) == vm.addr(vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY")), "First signer must be the sender");
        _sortByAddress(privKeys);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < privKeys.length; i++) {
            (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = vm.sign(privKeys[i], digest);
            signatures = abi.encodePacked(signatures, r, s, v);
        }
    }

    function _sortByAddress(uint256[] memory privKeys) internal {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < privKeys.length - 1; i++) {
            for (uint256 j = 0; j < privKeys.length - i - 1; j++) {
                if (vm.addr(privKeys[j]) > vm.addr(privKeys[j + 1])) {
                    (privKeys[j], privKeys[j + 1]) = (privKeys[j + 1], privKeys[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

Deployment using Create3
bytes memory bytecode = abi.encodeWithSignature("deploy(bytes32,bytes)", salt, create3Bytecode);
        bytes32 digest = keccak256(bytecode);

        // three signers for the deployment (this is mocked and only works in foundry chain)
        uint256[] memory signers = new uint256[](3);
        signers[0] = vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY");
        signers[1] = 1;
        signers[2] = 2;

        bytes memory signatures = _generateSignatures(signers, digest);

        Safe(payable(safeAddress)).execTransaction(
            address(create3), 0, bytecode, Enum.Operation.Call, 0, 0, 0, ZERO, payable(ZERO), signatures
        );


The signing logic looks good to me. I think the problem is in the digest you're signing.
For Safe, a Safe transaction hash needs to be signed, which is defined by the following EIP-712 struct:
export const EIP_DOMAIN = {
    EIP712Domain: [
        { type: "uint256", name: "chainId" },
        { type: "address", name: "verifyingContract" }, // Safe address
    ],
};

export const EIP712_SAFE_TX_TYPE = {
    // "SafeTx(address to,uint256 value,bytes data,uint8 operation,uint256 safeTxGas,uint256 baseGas,uint256 gasPrice,address gasToken,address refundReceiver,uint256 nonce)"
    SafeTx: [
        { type: "address", name: "to" },
        { type: "uint256", name: "value" },
        { type: "bytes", name: "data" },
        { type: "uint8", name: "operation" },
        { type: "uint256", name: "safeTxGas" },
        { type: "uint256", name: "baseGas" },
        { type: "uint256", name: "gasPrice" },
        { type: "address", name: "gasToken" },
        { type: "address", name: "refundReceiver" },
        { type: "uint256", name: "nonce" },
    ],
};

Safe contract has a function getTransactionHash which you can use to generate the hash on-chain. So, using this function, the deployment code becomes:
bytes memory bytecode = abi.encodeWithSignature("deploy(bytes32,bytes)", salt, create3Bytecode);
uint256 nonce = Safe(payable(safeAddress)).nonce();
bytes32 txHash = Safe(payable(safeAddress)).getTransactionHash(
                     address(create3), 0, bytecode, Enum.Operation.Call, 0, 0, 0, ZERO, payable(ZERO), nonce
                 );

// three signers for the deployment (this is mocked and only works in foundry chain)
uint256[] memory signers = new uint256[](3);
signers[0] = vm.envUint("PRIVATE_KEY");
signers[1] = 1;
signers[2] = 2;

bytes memory signatures = _generateSignatures(signers, txHash);

Safe(payable(safeAddress)).execTransaction(
    address(create3), 0, bytecode, Enum.Operation.Call, 0, 0, 0, ZERO, payable(ZERO), signatures
);

Notice: I edited the code using the StackOverflow editor, so there might be some mistakes.
